# How can I streamline the workflow of writing a React webapp inside a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Right now, I just ran create-react-app inside /src/main, creating /src/main/webapp, and then run `npm start` in that folder, and `gradle runBoot` in the root folder.

This leads to several problems - the most difficult of which is that I can't consume the API in the Spring Boot project due to CSRF protection.

The main problem is that while the create-ract-app server runs at :3000, the Spring Boot app runs at :8080, and while I can of course  `npm build` and use gradle to move the files to the correct location to test if my code works, that workflow is incredibly slow when you need to do it every two minutes. Not to mention that I get a production build of the React app, so I can't even understand the error messages.

I could probably work around the CSRF problem, but that still isn't a great solution, and I KNOW that I'm not the first person who's had this problem, so I am willing to bet good money that one of you geniuses know just what to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I integrate a Java backend with any front end technology I want to use. Let's say the project name is `myapp`, then inside it, I create 2 folders like this

```
myapp
     .
     .
     ...backend
     ...frontend
```

Inside `backend` is where my Java code goes, `frontend` I put the frontend, self-explanatory.

With this setup, the frontend and backend can independently evolve.

One thing to keep in mind is that, like you said, your backend server needs to enable CORS, or else, you will get the infamous CORS error

Comment: Well, I was hoping for more details. The problem isn't where to put the files, but the workflow of working with two apps simultaneously, where one has to be compiled(!) through NPM/Webpack, while the other through Gradle.
Also, "enable CORS" isn't very detailed, though it gives me something to google :)

Comment: What I was trying to say is with this set up, you just cd into the directory where your package.json file is located and do `npm start` to start your local http server, you then have to start your desired Java application server to run your backend code, this way, your deployment artifact only contains your Java code, while the frontend code is deployed separately from your Java deployment artifact, so it makes your Java app deployment faster, and you don't have to copy the frontend code into your Java deployment artifact.

Comment: Because now the frontend code is deployed to a local http server which runs on different port, you need to set appropriate CORS headers to make cross-origin requests to your Java backend, in particular, the most important  response header is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, for development, set this header to `*`, for production, set it to the domain name under which your app is deployed

Comment: This is true. I was hoping to somehow integrate the NPM workflow into the Spring Boot workflow so that they were running on the same port all along, but I suppose this is the best I can get.

Comment: `npm start` starts its own local http server, your Java app server is a different server, 2 different servers can't run on the same port